# How do I add a role assignment in the IAM section of subscriptions using powershell? I&#39;m looking to add &quot;Reader&quot; to a service principal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rbac

[image]

See my Azure Portal. I'm looking to add the "Reader" role my service principal. How would I do this in Powershell?

Comment: Step 1: [Review the relevant vendor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell)

Comment: Fairly well documented and your question doesn't show any effort in doing some research. Voting to close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of below PowerShell command to add **Reader** role to the service principal under subscription:

```
$spId = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "sp_Name").id
$subscriptionId = "your_subscription_Id"

New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spId `
-RoleDefinitionName "Reader" `
-Scope "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where **`Reader`** role added successfully to **service principal** under subscription level like this:

[image]